# Reach a computer on home network when it's connected to VPN

Tags: lan, openvpn, vncserver

I have an old desktop computer without keyboard or screen in a closet. I control it via a VNC-server within my LAN. Now I'm thinking about running a VPN-client on it. Will that only change the public IP-address, or will it also make it impossible to reach from within the LAN?

Comment: As to part 2:  or will it also make it impossible to reach from within the LAN?`: that depends on your VPN client. Look up spliot tunneling.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install something like openvpn on it and access over the vpn or lan.  VNC will bind to all the available network interfaces.

What I like to do is have a server in the cloud that is my vpn server.  Then the machines I'm administering and my own have openvpn client installs.  Then I can ssh or vnc whether I'm on the same lan or elsewhere.  Then I also never have to deal with firewall issues at client sites.  I have a few devices installed onsite for a clients network and it gives me a way to peek in on the network remotely if necessary.